# Azure - trigger notification from service bus queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-notificationhub, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to create the following process:

An **IoT device** sends a message to the **IoT Hub** which in turn, if the message contains some value, triggers a notification to all of the registered android devices through the **Notification Hub**.

At first, I do not care what is the content of the message itself, and I just want to trigger a notification on every incoming message.

I have managed to set up the IoT device and connect it to the IoT hub.
I have also managed to set up the Notification Hub, and connect it with the android app, in a way that when I use the "test send" in the Notification Hub, a notification is received on the android device.

In order to connect both ends (IoT Hub and Notification Hub), I tried to follow the following tutorial: https://www.developer.com/ws/android/sending-notifications-to-mobile-apps-from-azure-function-apps.html

In addition, I have added routing from the IoT Hub to the appropriate queue in the service bus.

Now, whenever the IoT device sends a message to the hub, I can see that the queue receives a message. However, I can't seem to use the queue to trigger the notification.

The `ServiceHubQueueTrigger` function I have added has the following error in the portal:

```
Error:

Function (ServiceBusQueueTrigger1) Error: The binding type(s) 'notificationHub' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
```

Its `function.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "notificationqueue",
      "connection": "ServiceBusConnection",
      "accessRights": "manage"
    },
    {
      "name": "notification",
      "type": "notificationHub",
      "hubName": "<hub-name>",
      "connection": "NotificationConnString",
      "platform": "gcm",
      "tagExpression": "",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

where `hub-name` is the name of the Notification Hub.

How can I trigger the notifications to the android devices through the queue?
Is there a way to trigger them directly from an `IoT Hub Event Trigger` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a simple 1.x vs 2.x Functions version problem indeed.

To solve it, if you are using the Azure portal:

1. Create a new `Function App`.
2. In the `Function App Settings`, set the version to `~1`:
   [image]
   Note that for a new Function App, the option to set the version won't be grayed out and you could set it to ~1.
3. Then, follow the guide at the link in the quetion.

If you are using Visual Studio, simply choose v1 when creating the function.
[image]

As written in Microsoft's documentation, Notification binding do not support Functions 2.x, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can trigger an Azure Function directly from incoming IoT Hub events. See one of my samples here: https://github.com/sebader/iotedge-end2end/blob/master/CloudFunctions/IotHubMessageProcessor.cs

```
public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "iothubevents_cs", ConsumerGroup = "receiverfunction")]EventData message, ILogger log)
{
  log.LogInformation($"IotHubMessageProcessor received a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)}");
}
```

IoT Hub Function Binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use the function to trigger the android notifciations?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs

Comment: That brings me back to the error I received when trying to add the `notificationHub` type to the `function.json`. It doesn't recognize the type, and I can't seem to set up the function. I don't know if it is related to 1.x vs 2.x versions of functions, but It happens on all functions I try to create through the portal.